# CircleCI CLI: "Err: Not found" when running "circleci local execute build"

Tags: circleci

I have installed CircleCI CLI (Windows) to test my `.circleci/config.yml` file locally before committing and pushing.

The file looks like this:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: docker:20.10.8-git
    steps:
      - run: echo "Hello world"
```

I've tried two different ways of running this command:

Method 1:

```
circleci local execute build
```

Method 2 (based on documentation saying version 2.1 and up requires process.yml):

```
circleci config process .circleci/config.yml > process.yml
circleci local execute -c process.yml build
```

In either case, the error is the highly unspecific:

```
Error: Not Found
```

The config file works when pushed to CircleCI. Additionally, it passes:

```
circleci config validate
```

I have, as a bit of a long shot, tried pulling the `docker:20.10.8-git` image, suspecting that's what it can't find.

The CLI is configured with `circleci setup`. The supplied API token is my personal CircleCI API token.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue and I got it working by installing an older version of circleci. This one that worked for me: v0.1.24435

Though I am using Mac and not sure what is the way to do it on Windows.

For Mac it's this way:
You would have to use alternative installation method from official docs:
https://circleci.com/docs/local-cli/#alternative-installation-method

Using the below worked to specify the version:
`curl -fLSs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-cli/master/install.sh | sudo VERSION="0.1.24435" bash`